# "Go up to top level" Windows 7 FTP explorer

Tags: windows-7, ftp

In Windows 7 you can [connect to an FTP server natively](http://www.redmondpie.com/access-ftp-sites-natively-in-windows-7/).

However, in a client like FileZilla, you can click the little ".." to go up one level.  But you can't do that in Windows 7, can you?  You are stuck considering the "top level" as the folder the FTP server decided to start you out at, even if there *are* accessible folders at levels above where you started.

Comment: Does typing "../" after the address work?

Comment: Well the thing is the "path" displayed in Windows explorer bar is C:\Users\B\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\MyServer, so you can't append ".." or else it goes up one level to "Network Shortcuts", which isn't very useful

Comment: Well, I tried typing ftp:// sitename.com into Windows Explorer (without the space) and I could type ../ after the address.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to an FTP site by mapping it (as in the linked example) to a local folder, you are stuck as it being the 'root' and you can't escape it.   It's like mapping a drive letter to a shared folder with regular Windows networking, if you mapped it as "F:" you can't get to "F:.." even if you have access to the folder above the share that you mapped to.

If you need to get to the folder above, you need to map to that folder (instead, or as well).

If you need to be hopping virtual folders on an FTP site, then a full-fledged FTP client (like FileZilla, or Windows' command-line FTP) is probably your best (only?) bet.